# Magento2 programmatically set value for specific attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

I created a drop-down attribute called "marketing" with 2 values : "sale" & "new" and I like to use a cron script that check every day :

- if a product has a special price (or a catalog rule) => attribute "marketing" set to "sale"
- if a product has no special price => attribute "marketing" empty
- if a product is set to new from/to date => attribute "marketing" set to "new" or nothing

Idea is to filter in a catalog list all products that are "on sale" or "new". I know ho to check the conditions but not how to set the correct value for this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

In your cron script, you can add the below code to fetch `marketing` dropdown attribute all options and values.

```
$this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'marketing');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

$attributeValue = [];
foreach($options as $option) {
    $attributeValue[$option['label']] = $option['value'];    
}
```

then you can use directly value to set the data in product like below:

```
$product->setMarketing($attributeValue['new'])
$product->setMarketing($attributeValue['sale'])
```

Hope this help !!

Comment: It works fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can directly save attribute using below code

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
\Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action $action
    ) 
{
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->productActionObject = $action;
}

public function execute() {
    $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'c_lager');

    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 0)
            continue;
        $options_final[$value['label']] = $value['value'];   
    }

    //write your code to get data 'new' or 'sale' for $product

    //save attribute without triggering reindex
    $this->productActionObject->updateAttributes([$product->getId()], array('marketing' => $options_final['new']), 0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue) below could set custom attribute successfully.

`$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
 $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
 $this->productRepository->save($product);`